# How to force thread to wait for gui loading on android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, xamarin.android

I start another heavy thread that play sound from android gui thread onCreate or onStart. After this gui not render, but music is playin about 20-30 seconds. Than gui rendered and everyting become normal. How i can force start my heavy thread start only after gui was rendered?

p.s. I actualy use monodroid

Answer (score 1):

I would insist to start sound inside `onResume()` it is the state of Activity where Activity is in foreground, so your UI would be loaded at this stage. See the [**Activity LifeCycle**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) `onStart()` is executed before `onResume()` so it might be the reason for your problem.

Comment: Better but stil there is some time before gui renders

Comment: you might be doing some heavy task before GUI renders, that making it react late.

Comment: I have separate splash acrivity where I load sounds. But I show this activity after sounds loaded

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a boolean variable `isUiLoaded` for that, Your worker thread should check this variable before starting... 'isUiLoaded' should be **false** by default and must be assigned to **true** inside onStart() or OnCreate() of the Activity which loads the UI.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that way. But I am not sure that it will help

Comment: Second answer was more elegant

Comment: It is undoubtedly, still You need to stop the thread inside OnStop() of the Activity otherwise thread will be running in the background even if the Activity stops..